# The csv results for sets 1 and 2 are not showing

Tags: r, shiny, rscript, rshiny

The code below takes a CSV file from the local computer and displays it on the main panel. Unfortunately, the code does not run, which means it does not display the intended CSV results while choosing options like "set1," "set2," and so on. I am new in R shiny..  Could anyone please assist me in resolving the problem?

```
library(here)
library(shiny)


set1_path <- here("set1.csv")
set2_path <-here("set2.csv")
set3_path <-here("set3.csv")
set4_path <- here("set4.csv")


set1<- read.csv(set1_path)
set2 <- read.csv(set2_path)
set3 <- read.csv(set3_path)
set4 <- read.csv(set4_path)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
shinyApp(
  ui = tagList(
    navbarPage(
      theme = "spacelab",
      
      tabPanel("report extracting",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file1", "Select datasets:",
                           accept = c(
                             "text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv"),
                           
                           
                 ),
                 # tags$hr(),
                 # checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 # textInput("txt", "Study info:", "Study name read"),
                 # sliderInput("slider", "Tables to read:", 1, 100, 30),
                 # tags$h5("Prepare extraction"),
                 selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a Domain", choices = c("domain1", "domain2", "domain3", "domain4")),
                 tableOutput("preview"),
                 actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary"),
                 # actionButton("dataset", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
                 
                 #Reading extracted datasets 
                 # Input: Choose dataset ----
                 selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                             choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "set1", "set2", "set3", "set4")),
                 
                 # Button
                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
                 
               
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("table"),
                 # tableOutput("contents"),
                 tabsetPanel(
                   
                   tabPanel("PDF File select",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table"),
                            h3("Extracting..."),
                            # selectInput("pdfExtract1", "Pick a Domain", choices = c("domain1", "domain2", "domain3", "domain4")),
                            # tableOutput("preview"),
                            # actionButton("pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
                            # downloadButton("download", "Download .tsv")
                            
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Raw data", "TBD"),
                   tabPanel("Summary data", "TBD")
                 )
               )
      ), # end of first tabpanel
      tabPanel("calculation",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file2", "Select datasets:",
                           accept = c(
                             "text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             ".csv")
                 ),
                 tags$hr(),
                 checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                 textInput("txt2", "domain info:", "report"),
                 sliderInput("slider", "Tables to read:", 1, 100, 30),
                 tags$h5("calculation"),
                 actionButton("dataset2", "Extract", class = "btn-primary")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("contents2"),
                 
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Datasets",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table2"),
                            h3("Summarizing...")
                   )
                 )
               )
      ),
      tabPanel("study compare",
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput("file3", "compare:"),
                 textInput("txt3", "Study info:", "Study name read"),
                 tags$h5("calculation"),
                 actionButton("action2", "Compare", class = "btn-primary")
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("PDF File select",
                            h4("Domains"),
                            tableOutput("table3"),
                            h3("Comparing..."),
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Summary data", "TBD")
                 )
               )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    
    # output$contents <- renderTable({
    #   # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    #   # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    #   # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    #   # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    #   # be found.
    #   inFile <- input$file1
    #   
    #   if (is.null(inFile))
    #     return(NULL)
    #   
    #   read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    # })
    # output$contents2 <- renderTable({
    #   # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    #   # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    #   # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    #   # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    #   # be found.
    #   inFile <- input$file2
    #   
    #   if (is.null(inFile))
    #     return(NULL)
      
    #   read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
    # })
    # output$txtout <- renderText({
    #   paste(input$txt, input$slider, format(input$date), sep = ", ")
    # })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df <- c("datasetsx")
    })
    output$table2 <- renderTable({
      df <- c("datasetsy")
    })
    output$table3 <- renderTable({
      df <- c("datasetsz")
    })
    observeEvent(input$dataset, {
      source("domain.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    observeEvent(input$dataset2, {
      source("calculation.R", local = TRUE)
    })
    #Domain level Selection   
    observeEvent(input$pdfExtract, {    
      if(input$pdfExtract1 == "PP"){ 
        source("domain1.R", local = TRUE)
      }
      else if(input$pdfExtract1 == "MA"){
        source("domain2.R", local = TRUE)
      }
      else if (input$pdfExtract1 =="CL"){
        source("domain3.R", local =TRUE)
      }
      else{
        source("domain4.R", local =TRUE)
      }
    })
    # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
    datasetInput <- reactive({
      switch(input$dataset,
             "set1" = set2,
             "set2" = set2,
             "set3" = set3,
             "set4" = set4)
    })
    
    # Table of selected dataset ----
    output$table <- renderTable({
      datasetInput()
    })
    
    # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )
    
  }
)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue, but you have a missing quotation mark `"`. The line `df <- c("datasetsy)` should be `df <- c("datasetsy")`.

Comment: Yes, the same has been updated. There is a problem with the code "datasetInput - reactive( switch(input$dataset," I'm unable to locate it in order to obtain the set1 and set2 results.

Comment: The line `"set1" = set2` is obviously wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a minimum example from your Code. You have to work on a few things.
At first you need an eventReactive:

```
datasetInput <- eventReactive( input$pdfExtract, {
      switch(input$dataset,
             "set1" = set1
             )     })
```

If the user picks a set, nothing is happening, until the user hits the "pdfExtract-button". Then a datasetinput is made. Which we call here to view in our main panel:

```
 # Table of selected dataset ----
    output$table <- renderTable({
        datasetInput()
      })
```

The whole program:

```
library(shiny)
    
    set1 <- structure(list(This = c(1L, 7L, 3L), is_the = c(5L, 8L, 2L), 
                               header = c(9L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            -3L))
    options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      theme = "spacelab",
                     selectInput(inputId = "dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                                 choices = c("SelectDataSet ", "set1")),
                     
                     actionButton(inputId = "pdfExtract", "Extract", class = "btn-primary"),
                    
                   mainPanel(
                     tableOutput(outputId = "table"),
                   )
        )
    
    server = function(input, output,session) {
        
        # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
        datasetInput <- eventReactive( input$pdfExtract, {
          switch(input$dataset,
                 "set1" = set1
                 )     })
        
        # Table of selected dataset ----
        output$table <- renderTable({
            datasetInput()
          })
        
      }
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> Additionally you have output$table <- renderTable which you call twice in server, i guess thats why R does not load any tables in your code.